# buildozer - using a different python version (not default 2.7.2)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I'm trying to compile an Andriod apk file with a more recent version than what Buildozer uses by default (2.7.2).

Reason being, I have a library that needs 2.7.7 or greater, and I'm not that confident in creating a full Python build myself with a specific lib.  The app runs perfectly on my Linux PC which runs 2.7.12.

Using Python 3.5 with Crystax gives me more problems again.  (I will try again if the solution above is not possible.)

Is this impossible, or too complex for someone who is 'Python intermediate'?  Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**  OK, looks like I need to compile a python for android from a repository from github.  Annnnd..... *the fun begins!*

Answer (score 0):

The code used to compile python2 is in the recipe [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/python2/__init__.py). Targeting a different python version would require updating all the patches and potentially making other changes depending on what is necessary for compatibility.

There was a PR for this at https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/775, which may be a useful reference. I don't know if it will work easily.

Going the python3 route with crystax is probably easier.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had a good look into using a different recipe for python2, but it's a bit beyond me for now.  Maybe in the future.